# Open pdf with Adobe Acrobat Reader and jump to bookmark

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I try to open the Adobe Acrobat Reader and then jump to a bookmark. But it doesn't work with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "acrord32.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"nameddest=S2\" C:\\temp\\xxx.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

How can I do this? - Important: I have to use the Acrobat Reader not Acrobat.

When I use `page=2` as a parameter it works. But not with the nameddest.
When I open the pdf, I see S2 as a bookmark in the second page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bookmarks and named destinations are not the same thing. You will have to [create a destination](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7ca7.w.html) in your PDF. If the rest of your code is correct, that should solve your problem.