# Opening a pdf in c# at specific bookmark

Tags: c#, pdf, bookmarks

I have a existing pdf which i want to open at specific bookmarks in c#. Below is the snippet of code i'm using

```
string filepath = Common.executivePath.ToString() + @"\helpfile.pdf";
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Adobe\\Reader10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"nameddest=Flexible Pavement Design\"  " + filepath;
myProcess.Start();
```

If the bookmark is a single word (i.e no spaces it works fine) it works fine.

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"nameddest=Preface\"  " + filepath;
```

Here the name of the bookmark is "Preface". Also if bookmark is nested inside another, that is also not working(i'm not sure about the syntax here).

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"nameddest=Preface/Disclaimer"  " + filepath;
```

Is there any other attribute other than arguments i should use to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open pdf with Adobe Acrobat Reader and jump to bookmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341269/open-pdf-with-adobe-acrobat-reader-and-jump-to-bookmark)

Comment: or a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423922/open-a-pdf-file-programmatically-at-a-named-destination