# Helpfile location based on event in C# form

Tags: c#, forms, events, helpfile

i have helpfile pdf .. I want to go to specific places in the helpfile based on what the user has selected in a particular form. 
Basically the question is How do i detect what is the highlighted(selected) field in a form in C#?

Comment: What are you using to access/display the PDF?  Perhaps a bit of code sample will help people understand how you are using the PDF as help file.  Also, do you need to use PDF, or could you perhaps use a chm file or HTML file?  May be easier to deal with other formats other than PDF.

Comment: You just posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168185/opening-a-pdf-in-c-sharp-at-specific-bookmark

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is Winform application, register HelpRequested event of each control on the form. This event has parameter "sender" which contains control, that requested help. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested.aspx?queryresult=true) sample code on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this properly, you just want to know what control is selected in the Form or what text is selected within that selected control?

For example, if you want to know what is selcted in a textbox, you can use:

```
this.txt_MyTextBox.SelectedText;
```

Alternatively, if you want to know which control is being focused at the moment:

[this.ActiveControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx); is probably what you want.

You can also handle each control differently based on what type it is.